# Is it possible to get access permission for a folder in local file system from browser

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

I want to make a local file editor. To open some files edit them and save them back. It's ok if it only works in Chrome. Using

```
<input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple />
```

I can read all the files and draw the file tree but I want to also be able to edit and save to these files. Even create new files and folders.

Is there any way to do it. I'm also ok with hacks that use Java or Flash or simply any other hack if HTML5 does not offer any solution.

Thanks

Comment: not possible. because of the local system security.

Comment: NO, these editors are implemented by upload-edit-download

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe what you are suggesting is possible; however, there is a different approach that should solve your problem.

If you take Microsoft's Online Word for example... They have it setup so you save document to the cloud and then can edit them with an online copy of Microsoft Word.

In otherwords, the user would upload a file. Your server would then take the file, display it and allow the user to edit the file. The user would then save the changes to the file. You can then provide an option to re-download the file.

To more closely emulate editing a file on the local file system, you can also setup a "temporarily" save on the server.

Essentially, the user uploads a file. The server would allow the user to view and edit the file. When the user wishes to save it, instead of saving the file on the server, give it back as a download to the user.

After the user leaves your site you can delete the copy of the file that is saved on your server.

Comment: This is most my competitor pages doing. I am looking to find if there is any possible way to make it work with file system. Because this is what I actually need. If they will download a Electron version of page it's easy but there are many other similar apps that needs downloading anyway.

Comment: @rturkek The problem what you are saying is that it is a massive security risk. Browsers are not post to let the internet access the local machine. In fact they be designed to prevent that from happening. If you want to create a local editor, the only secure and acceptable way with current technology is to create a desktop application.

Comment: We can even discuss how to run executables from browser that gives access to file system. Especially if they can work in multiple OS's. But I want to make sure there is no possible way even including Java or any other tool

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question has changed since more featues have been added to web standards.

In modern times it is possible to do what you require with the WebAPI *File System API*. In particular you can use `window.showOpenFilePicker()` to open the browsers files system UI to get access to a file (which is represented by a (promise to) a  `FileSystemFileHandle` object. In the same vein you can use say `window.showSaveFilePicker()` to save data to a local file.

Do bare in mind that some of the API features are gated by user activation, which means for example that you can only open a request to get access to a file by say running a Js function as a result of a button click.